# How to convert a whole flutter Screen to pdf?

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter E-commerce App which has a orderDetails page , I want to convert the whole page to pdf using flutter pdf package, as it would be more convinent because the data is retrived from FirebaseFirestore. Is there a way around I can achieve this ?

sub: I want to convert the whole flutter screen to pdf using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture the screen using this package [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)

then add that image to pdf document and save it

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart ' as pw;

Future getPdf(Uint8List screenShot) async {
  pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.Expanded(
          child: pw.Image(PdfImage.file(pdf.document, bytes: screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain)
        );
      },
    ),
  );
  File pdfFile = File('Your path + File name');
  pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
}
```

Comment: the link you have provided is of the pdf package for flutter , https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot is this the package you were refering as screenshot ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my bad. Yeah this is the one.

Comment: thank you for your answer will give it a try and let you know about the result .

Comment: @IshangaVidusha I got this error ``` The argument type 'PdfImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider ``` on the line PdfImage(pdf.document, bytes: screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain). do you have any answer for it. it would be really helpful

Comment: @basudevnayak can you help me with it

Answer (score 3):

you need to

```
 1. flutter pub add pdf
 2. flutter pub add screenshot
```

Then

```
 Future<void> getPdf(Uint8List screenShot) async {
      final pdf = pw.Document();
      pdf.addPage(
        pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
      final output = File('Your path + File name');
      await output.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

full details:
load dependencies in pubspec.yaml:

```
 screenshot: 
  share_plus: 
  path_provider:
  permission_handler:
```

import packages in your dart file:

```
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

  shareImage() async {

    final uint8List = await screenshotController.capture();
    String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    String fileName ="myFile";
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      File file = await File('$tempPath/$fileName.png').create();
      file.writeAsBytesSync(uint8List);
      await Share.shareFiles([file.path]);
    }
  }
```

and call shareImage() on any place:

```
 GestureDetector(
   onTap: (){ shareImage();},
   child: ........,
  ),
```

remember to wrap your desire widget in:

```
Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Text("This text will be captured as image"),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  newest solution will be
    shareImage() async {
    final uint8List = await screenshotController.capture();
        String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    String fileName =" ";>>>>>your file name between ""
    File file = await File('$tempPath/$fileName" }.png').create();
    file.writeAsBytesSync(uint8List!);
     await Share.shareFiles([file.path]);
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Mendes! Thanks for your suggestion! The code looks sound! Would you mind elaborating a bit more on how this fits in to a full widget?

Comment: https://github.com/vmendesneto/calculadora_capital/blob/master/lib/src/save_pdf/pdf.dart

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart ' as pw;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

Future screenToPdf(String fileName,Uint8List screenShot) async {
  pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.Expanded(
          child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
  String path = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  File pdfFile = await File('$path/$fileName.pdf').create();

  pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
  await Share.shareFiles([pdfFile.path]);
}
```